# Parsing JSON in one go

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, strings, json

I need to parse a simple JSON string (flat JSON, no hierarchy) for keys and values, and there is a system constraint that I cannot use any built-in JSON library and can only read a string once due to latency requirements. I need to use Python 2.7.x series and cannot use a higher version.

Currently, my major concern for below code is, I still do a bit more than one pass string parsing, since I need to go backward/forward to remove unnecessary characters around a word, which is what `wordBeautify` does.

This is a follow-up to ["Json String Parsing"](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/121262/json-string-parsing)

```
def wordBeautify(word1, beginIndex, endIndex):
    noMeaningChars=[' ', '"', '{', ',', ':','}']
    while word1[beginIndex] in noMeaningChars:
        beginIndex+=1
    while word1[endIndex] in noMeaningChars:
        endIndex-=1
    return (beginIndex,endIndex+1)

def parseElegant2(str1):

    keyStr=''
    valueStr=''
    beginWord = False
    isKey=True
    beginIndex=0
    endIndex=0

    for i in range(len(str1)):

        if str1[i]==':':
            endIndex=i-1
            (x,y) = wordBeautify(str1, beginIndex, endIndex)
            keyStr=str1[x:y]
            print "key string " + keyStr
            beginIndex=i+1
        elif str1[i]==',' or str1[i]=='}':
            endIndex=i
            (x,y) = wordBeautify(str1, beginIndex, endIndex)
            valueStr=str1[x:y]
            beginIndex=i+1
            print "value string " + valueStr
            print 'key and value, '+ keyStr, valueStr

def parseElegant(str1):

    keyStr=''
    valueStr=''
    beginWord = False
    isKey=True
    beginIndex=0
    endIndex=0

    for i in range(len(str1)):

        if str1[i] == '"' and beginWord==False:
            beginWord=True
            beginIndex = i+1
        elif str1[i] == '"' and beginWord==True:
            beginWord=False
            endIndex=i
            if beginIndex<endIndex:
                print "get word, " + str1[beginIndex:endIndex]
        elif str1[i]==':':
            keyStr=str1[beginIndex:endIndex]
        elif str1[i]==',':
            valueStr=str1[beginIndex:endIndex]
            print 'key and value, '+ keyStr, valueStr

if __name__ == "__main__":

    #JSONString = '{ "id": 1, "name": "A green door", "price": 12.50, "tags": ["home", "green"]}'
    JSONString1 = '{ "id": "1", "name": "A green door", "price": "12.50", "tags": "home green"}'
    JSONString2 = '{ "id": 1, "name": "A green door", "price": 12.50, "tags": "home green"}'

    parseElegant2(JSONString1)
    parseElegant2(JSONString2)
```

Comment: One thing we didn't cover in the previous version, is that this could benefit from linking to the previous version, and also list some of the improvements you've made from the first version! :-)

Comment: Would it be considered parsing to check if the string has valid JSON characters - such as:    if   ( '{' not in str1 or '}' not in str1 ): Exception('badjson', abort')     ??

Comment: @cgseller, good catch. In my problem, JSON is considered to be good format from upper stream processors. Your advice is appreciated for the code I posted, for correctness and reliability, Currently, my major concern for below code is, I still do a bit more than one pass string parsing, since I need to go backward/forward to remove unnecessary characters around a word, which is what `wordBeautify` does.

Comment: If you want (and it's a good idea) to have a single pass, then consider using a stream, looking only at the (single) next character at a time and then build a state machine around it.

Comment: @ferada, good idea. My question is more about how to implement the specific logic in details. If you have any comments for my code and my question posted, it will be highly appreciated. :)

Comment: Start bounty and your advice is appreciated for the code I posted, for correctness and reliability, Currently, my major concern for below code is, I still do a bit more than one pass string parsing, since I need to go backward/forward to remove unnecessary characters around a word, which is what `wordBeautify` does.

Comment: @Tersosauros, done. Have a nice weekend. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, let me say well done on the progress made from your [first question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/121262/json-string-parsing) to [now](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/121328/parsing-json-in-one-go/122109#top)!

### <sub>[Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is for *reviewing* code</sub>

As you seem to be seeking advice "*about how to **implement***" an idea (*i.e.* streams), I think you may be better off [asking on Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), since that is [a more appropriate place for questions about <sup>*"*</sup>*software architecture and design*<sup>*"*</sup> and <sup>*"*</sup>*algorithm and data structure concepts*<sup>*"*</sup>](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).
[Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is <sup>*"*</sup>*not for questions about broken code, [hypothetical code](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3649/my-question-was-closed-as-being-off-topic-what-are-my-options/3652#3652), or non-existent code, as such questions will be closed as off-topic.*<sup>*"*</sup> (taken from [this help page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)).

---

I **can** see that you have code already, and are seeking to *improve* it (in a way that doesn't add any functionality) - so I consider your question to be on-topic.  Although your desire to learn about **other** ways of implementing it entirely may not be best placed on this site.

---

### A Quick Review

**Remove old code**
You have *included* the (now unused) code for `parseElegant` (version 1).  While I can understand you not wanting to erase this, you have already linked to your previous question (which contains the old code).  Including version 1 here just adds ~24 lines for reviewers to have to scroll through.

**Can't you just use `strip`?**
The `wordBeautify` function (which you are seeking to make redundant/remove) *seems* to be **VERY** similar to the [Python built-in string.strip method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip)?

Consider the following code:

```
test="{:foo }"
(x,y)=wordBeautify(test,0,len(test)-1)
a=test[x:y]
b=test.strip(' "{,:}')
```

<sub>**Result**</sub>:  `a` and `b` both work out to be "foo"!

**Use better variable names!**
At present, your `parseElegant2` function takes an argument called `str1`.  While it is obvious that this means something along the lines of *the first string* - it is not actually particularly **helpful** in knowing what that variable *represents*.

Something more like `json`, `text_candidate`, or `candidate` may be better - as it expresses that this is a long text containing json, or something that is a *candidate* to be processed into JSON.

You have a similar issue in `wordBeautify`, with `word1`.  This could just be named `word`, or similar.

**Return is better than print**
I've noticed that in your function you are not `return`'ing any values.  Instead you are just `print`'ing to the standard output (STDOUT).
Is this your goal? Or will your program eventually need to construct some kind of data structure (such as a `dict`) of the JSON values?

I would recommend refactoring your code to return a data structure, and have your function write the JSON values into that data structure.

---

### A word on string stream processing

As [@ferada](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/54571/ferada) [commented](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/121328/parsing-json-in-one-go/122109#comment-226835), I think you should <sup>"</sup>*consider using a stream, looking only at the (single) next character at a time and then build a state machine around it.*<sup>"</sup>, however your current program is **not** doing this.

Instead, your loop is going through the *indices* of the string.  And is (at present), also calling your `wordBeautify` function to do the same (with indices).

Rather than using `for i in range(len(str1)):`, as you currently are - I would recommend that you *loop through the characters themselves* (one at a time, as [@ferada](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/54571/ferada) suggested).  Thus, your loop may look more like: `for c in str1:`

This way, you are essentially **forced** into *only* looking at the current character. (*i.e.* you are unable to increment/decrement any number value to go forwards or backwards in the string.)

---

### Constructing a state machine

From [the Wikipedia article about Finite-state machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine):

> A [finite-state machine (FSM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) or simply [**state machine**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine), is a mathematical model of computation used to design computer programs.  It is conceived as an abstract machine that can be in *one* of any finite number of states.  The machine is in *only one state at a time*, called the current state. It can change from one state to another when triggered, this is called a **transition**.  ***A particular state machine is defined by a list of its states, and the triggering condition for each transition.***
>    
> <sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

You can [read the article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) for more background information, but essentially your are seeking to construct a [state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine).  As you can read in the last sentence (that I've bolded), this requires:

- a list of states
- the trigger conditions for each state transition

---

### What are the states?

Luckily, [the official JSON website (JSON.org)](http://json.org/) *actually **gives** us* these exact things!
In the form of [railroad diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_diagram).  Specifically, they [tell us](http://json.org/) that:

> An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs. An object begins with { (left brace) and ends with } (right brace). Each name is followed by : (colon) and the name/value pairs are separated by , (comma).
>   
>   [image: An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs. An object begins with { (left brace) and ends with } (right brace)...]
>   <sub>(source: [json.org](http://json.org/object.gif))</sub>

So we know that **STRING** is a *state*, for example.  They [also tell us](http://json.org/) *how* we get into (and out of) the **STRING** state:

> A string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, wrapped in double quotes...
>   
>   [image: A string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, wrapped in double quotes...]
>   <sub>(source: [json.org](http://json.org/string.gif))</sub>

So we know that a **STRING** state is *triggered* when we encounter a `"` (quote) character. (And that it ends the same way.)
<sub>**Note:**  For now, let's ignore the backslash (`\`) *escape* style string components.</sub>

We also are told what a *VALUE* might be as well:

> A value can be a string in double quotes, or a number, or true or false or null...
>   
>   [image: A value can be a string in double quotes, or a number, or true or false or null...]
>   <sub>(source: [json.org](http://json.org/value.gif))</sub>

This gives us another *state*, namely **NUMBER** - since a value can be a number.

### <sup>Some limitations <sub>(Let's not reinvent the whole wheel)</sub></sup>

We already know that you only want to deal with **"***flat JSON (no hierarchy) for keys and values***"**.
So, we'll forget about *OBJECT* and *ARRAY* in the diagram above. ;-)

Let's also (just to make it easy), ignore the fact that a value can be `true`, `false`, or `null`.  (*i.e.* it is either a string or a number).

### <sub>The states so far</sub>

So far, we have been able to use the [official JSON.org website diagrams](http://json.org/) to determine we have the following two states:

- **STRING**
- **NUMBER**

We also know that a string is *triggered* by the condition: `c=='"'` (where `c` is our stream's *current character*).

But how is a **NUMBER** triggered?
Well [the JSON.org website](http://json.org/) has a [rather complicated way of detecting numbers](http://json.org/number.gif) (which takes into account negative numbers, scientific notation, etc).  but for these purposes let's just say that a **NUMBER** is *triggered* by a sequence of 1 or more of the following characters: `0123456789.` (the decimal point is included).

### <sup>Other transitions</sup>

If we look back at [the first railroad diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pkCG.gif):
[image: An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs. An object begins with { (left brace) and ends with } (right brace)...]

We can see that the **COLON** (`:`) and **COMMA** (`,`) characters are also transitions between states..

---

### Putting it all together

If we combine all of these states and transitions, plus the idea of a character (rather than index) loop, and the other improvements I've mentioned - we can produce a single function which is capable of *processing a JSON string "**all at once**"*:

```
def parseElegant3(candidate):
    READY=0
    STRING=1
    NUMBER=3
    COLON=-1
    COMMA=-2

    search={'"':STRING,  ':':COLON,  ',':COMMA,  STRING:'"',  COMMA:','}
    NOP=" {\t}\r\n"
    stringIgnore='{,:}'
    numbers='0123456789.'

    result={}
    if not len(candidate):
        return result
    accumulator=""
    mostRecentKey=None

    state=READY
    for c in candidate:
        newState=state
        if state is READY:
            if c in NOP:continue
            if c in numbers:
                newState=NUMBER
            if c in search.keys():
                newState=search[c]
        if newState is COLON:
            newState=READY
            if len(accumulator):
                accumulator=accumulator.strip()
                result[accumulator]=None
                mostRecentKey=accumulator
                accumulator=""
            else:
                state=READY
                continue
        elif newState is COMMA:
            newState=READY
        elif newState is NUMBER and not state is NUMBER:
            accumulator+=c
        if state is STRING and newState is STRING:
            if c in stringIgnore:continue
            if c==search[STRING]:
                newState=READY
                if not mostRecentKey is None:
                    result[mostRecentKey]=accumulator
                    accumulator=""
                    mostRecentKey=None
            else:
                accumulator+=c
        elif state is NUMBER:
            if c in numbers:
                accumulator+=c
            else:
                if c in NOP:continue
                assert c == search[COMMA]
                try:
                    result[mostRecentKey]=int(accumulator)
                except ValueError:
                    result[mostRecentKey]=float(accumulator)
                accumulator=""
                mostRecentKey=None
                newState=READY
        state=newState
    return result

JSONString = '{ "id": 1, "name": "A green door", "price": 12.50, "tags": "home green"}'

parseElegant3(JSONString)
```

Comment: Very nice post, Tersosauros! Vote up. Two quick questions, (1) what are the logical meaning of "accumulator"? And (2) you distinguish between STRING and NUMBER because for NUMBER it does not have to be quoted by `"`? Thanks. :)

Comment: Another quick question is, for your data structure `search`, it is actually a dictionary, correct? For example, key is `"`, value is STRING, key is `:`, and value is COLON, correct? :)

Comment: Thank you!
(1) The accumulator is where stream data (characters) are stored after reading and before being put into the `result`.
(2) Yes, a STRING is always "quoted", where-as a NUMBER is never like that.  a NUMBER also can only have the characters `0123456789.` - where-as a string can have anything (except for a quote).
Yes, `search` is basically a dictionary of the _trigger) characters.

Comment: Thanks Tersosauros, in your code, `state is STRING`, does it mean at the begin of a reading a string, or in the middle of reading a string? Thanks.

Comment: Also for statement, `if not mostRecentKey is None`, why not just write as `if mostRecentKey`? I think you just need to check if `mostRecentKey` is None or not? Thanks.

Comment: if the state is STRING it means we have already triggered the transition from the READY state into STRING (by finding a `"`) - so it means we are in the middle.
Yes, you *could* use `if mostRecentKey` - **however** that will mean any `mostRecentKey` value that evaluates to false **cannot be a key name**.  Using `if not mostRecentKey is None` gets around this by being more explicit.

Comment: @Tersosauros maybe `if mostRecentKey is not None` is easier to read (and understand)

Comment: Thanks Tersosauros, nice catch and vote up, but how your solution resolve the problem `mostRecentKey` has some value, but not related to a key? I see you just check for null or not by `if not mostRecentKey is None`? --  “that will mean any ·mostRecentKey· value that evaluates to false cannot be a key name”

Comment: BTW, Tersosauros, another quick question is, what is the logical meaning of READY status? I think it means we have completed either STRING, NUMBER, COLON, COMMA status and READY is a status means begin to enter either of such 4 status? Thanks.

Comment: BTW, Tersosauros , did a lot of debugging and learning from your code today and confused by the logical meaning of `stringIgnore='{,:}'`, and why do you ignore such two characters? Appreciate for clarification and example. :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about the `mostRecentKey` "problem"? *Obviously* you don't want a key of `None` in the `result`. Right?
I was talking about the idea you mentioned of using `if mostRecentKey` instead.  Also as @oliverpoolsaid, his syntax is probably more readable!

Comment: The `stringIgnore` variable is just a different name for the `noMeaningChars` one from the original code. It's just the characters that have no meaning in the input of a STRING.
It ignores them the same as `wordBeautify` did - but as part of one big loop (so it can all be done "in one go").

Comment: @Tersosauros, nice catch and vote up. Wondering why you need to use `stringIgnore`, other than using the same set of characters in`NOP` for STRING? Anything special for STRING? Thanks.

Comment: @Tersosauros, for the `mostRecentKey` question, let me rephrase, my question is, what is the issue do you think if I just write `if mostRecentKey` to replace `if not mostRecentKey is None`? Thanks.

Comment: @LinMa As [I said](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/121328/parsing-json-in-one-go/122119#comment-227813) `stringIgnore` is just the same as `noMeaningChars`.  The characters in `NOP` are for *parsing* the JSON. Where-as, the `stringIgnore`/`noMeaningChars` is used when processing STRING as you say.

Comment: Thanks Tersosauros, vote up. My question is why `NOP` and `stringIgnore`  `NOP=" {\t}\r\n"` and `stringIgnore='{,:}'` have different values?

Comment: Ahh, I see.  If `NOP` didn't have the whitespace characters (`\t`, `\r`, `\n`, and `' '` (space)) then each of these characters would need their own *state* in the state machine.  Putting them in `NOP` means we don't need more states (since they get ignored, as a NO-OP (NOP).

Comment: Thanks Tersosauros, vote up. :)

BTW, I edit my original post and re-write a new version of pseudo code (I do not handle some corner cases) based on your guidance of state machine, one point I think your code is a bit confusing to me is using two state variables -- `newState` and `state`, and I rewrite code using only one `state` variable, I am not 100% confident if my code is correct logic and your advice is highly appreciated. :)

Comment: And Tersosauros , another question is still about `stringIgnore`, here is your code,`stringIgnore='{,:}'`, my confusion is it seems you think such characters could be ignored in STRING `{`,`,`,`:`,`}`? Why? An example is appreciated. I think they are valid characters inside a STRING, please feel free to correct me. :)

Comment: BTW, Tersosauros, I post my new vesion of code here, and your advice is highly appreciated, thanks. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/122534/parsing-json-in-one-go-using-state-machine-solution

Comment: The `stringIgnore`, as with `noMeaningChars` inside `wordBeautify` in your original code, **only** removes those characters *from the start and end* of the STRING.  This is the same behaviour as `wordBeautify`, but implemented using `strip()` as I recommended in my comment on your question.

Comment: @ LinMa Voted up. If you are done with this question (and moving on to [your new one](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/122534/parsing-json-in-one-go-using-state-machine-solution) then please **accept** an answer on this question, as this is how the StackExchange network operates. I will take a look at your new question. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Tersosauros, my last question is if I just write `if mostRecentKey` to replace `if not mostRecentKey is None`, if not, could you show me an example why? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Tersosauros , appreciate clarify your code is peer to my `wordBeautify ` part of code, and my question actually is, why you are using two sets of characters `stringIgnore` and `NOP`? My `wordBeautify ` only use one set of no-meaning characters. Thanks. :)

Comment: And Tersosauros, for sure, I will definitely mark it as an answer after the above two small issues are resolved. :)

Comment: Yes, the `stringIgnore` is a "peer" to your `wordBeautify`, exactly
The reason my code has a `NOP` and your's didn't - is because your code had the two lines: `if str1[i]==':':` and `elif str1[i]==',' or str1[i]=='}':`.  Therefore (since you have no `else` block after those) your code *ignores* whitespace, etc without a variable.  Obviously for a state machine, we need a variable for this - so that it can be made explicit.

Comment: As I have said about `if not mostRecentKey is None`: "*you could use if mostRecentKey - however that will mean any mostRecentKey value that evaluates to false **cannot be a key name**. Using if not mostRecentKey is None gets around this by being more explicit.*"
So, again it's about an explicit coding style.

Comment: Thanks Tersosauros , I tried if `mostRecentKey` is an empty string, your code`if not mostRecentKey is None` will be True, but my code `if mostRecentKey` will be false, I think empty key cannot be used as valid result. And it is why I am asking. Your advice is highly appreciated. Vote up as well. :)

Comment: Ahh I see, well if you're willing to exclude empty keys as a possibility then **yes**, using your way of `if mostRecentKey` would make some sense - as it is more readable!

Comment: Thanks  Tersosauros for the clarification, the last question on this thread is about the `stringIgnore` you are using, currently you are assigning values of `'{,:}'` to `stringIgnore`, I think it may have issues, since if for a string (either key or value), if it is `"Hello, State Machine"`, since comma is in `stringIgnore`, you will change the string to `"Hello State Machine"`, which is not accurate. I may mis-understand your code, so please feel free to correct me. :)

Comment: BTW, I will mark this thread as answered when `stringIgnore` issue is clear and we can continue to discuss on the new thread using one state for state machine implementation. :)

Comment: As I've said, `stringIgnore` is a "peer" to your `wordBeautify` function's `noMeaningChars` string.  It is **just** used to `strip` characters from the **ENDS** of strings.  To quote a previous comment I made: "*The `stringIgnore`, as with `noMeaningChars` inside `wordBeautify` in your original code, **only** removes those characters from the start and end of the STRING. This is the same behaviour as `wordBeautify,` but implemented using `strip()` as I recommended in my comment on your question*".
So `"Hello, State Machine"` stays `"Hello, State Machine"`, but `",Hello State Machine"` doesn't.

Comment: Thanks Tersosauros, mark your answer as reply and grant 50 more points, appreciate all the help so far. :)

We can continue to discuss here (http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/122534/parsing-json-in-one-go-using-state-machine-solution) about whether using one state variable is good as well to make code simpler. Your advice is highly appreciated. :)

Answer (score -1):

If it's possible for you to convert the JSON string to a dictionary data structure like so:

```
d = eval(JSONString)
```

then you could use the

```
string.strip()
```

and

```
string.replace()
```

methods on the individual keys.

You could then either work with the dict/JSON as is, or rebuild it to resemble a string if necesssary.

Comment: Thanks user6026938, thanks for sharing the idea. Vote up. :)

It is not possible for me to "convert the JSON string to a dictionary data structure" in my specific problem and I have to write the raw parser. If you have any good implementation how to parse the JSON string only once, appreciate for sharing.