# Parsing JSON in one go using state machine solution

Tags: python, algorithm, parsing, python-2.x, json

I need to parse a simple JSON string (flat JSON, no hierarchy) for keys and values, and there is a system constraint that I cannot use any built-in JSON library and can only read a string once due to latency requirements. I need to use Python 2.7.x series and cannot use a higher version.

**Note:** This question is *version 3* of my code to solve this problem.

<sub>[**Version 1**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/121262/json-string-parsing) - answered by [@holroy](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/78136/holroy)</sub>
<sub>[**Version 2**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/121328/parsing-json-in-one-go) - answered by [@Tersosauros](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/96820/tersosauros)</sub>

This is a new version of code based on guidance from [@Tersosauros](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/96820/tersosauros)' post of the [previous version](/questions/121328/parsing-json-in-one-go). Note that I still do not handle some corner cases. I do not want to use two state variables as with [@Tersosauros](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/96820/tersosauros)' code, but rewrote using only one state variable. I am not 100% confident if my code is correct logic and your advice is highly appreciated.

```
READY = 0
COLON = 1
COMMA = 2
STRING = 3
NUMBER = 4

numbers='0123456789.'
NoOps=' {'

def parse(strJSON):
    state = READY
    lastKey=''
    lastValue=''
    temp=''
    result={}
    for c in strJSON:
        if state == READY:
            if c in NoOps:
                continue
            elif c == '"':
                state = STRING
            elif c == ':':
                lastKey=temp
                temp=''
                state = READY
            elif c == ',' or c=='}':
                lastValue=temp
                temp=''
                if lastKey:
                    result[lastKey]=lastValue
                    lastValue=''
                    lastKey=''
                    state=READY
            elif c in numbers:
                state=NUMBER
        elif state == STRING:
            if c == '"':
                state = READY
            else:
                temp += c
        if state == NUMBER:
            if c in NoOps or c==',' or c=='}':
                lastValue=temp
                temp=''
                if lastKey:
                    result[lastKey]=lastValue
                    lastValue=''
                    lastKey=''
                state=READY
            else:
                temp+=c

    if lastKey:
            result[lastKey]=lastValue

    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #JSONString = '{ "id": 1, "name": "A green door", "price": 12.50, "tags": ["home", "green"]}'
    JSONString1 = '{ "id": "1", "name": "A green door", "price": "12.50", "tags": "home green"}'
    JSONString2 = '{ "id": 1, "name": "A green door", "price": 12.50, "tags": "home green"}'
    print parse(JSONString1)
    print parse(JSONString2)
```

Comment: You should avoid variables names like `temp`, as this conveys nothing about what that variable represents.

Comment: @Tersosauros, good catch and vote up. If you could give advice whether  using one state variable is good as well, which makes code simpler than using state and newState, it will be great. :)

Comment: Yes, you should generally only ever need to track one state per FSM.  So since all your logic is contained within one, you would need only *one* `state` variable.

Comment: **NOTE** I have found an error in the way this version of your parser deals with integers.  See [my answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/122534/parsing-json-in-one-go-using-state-machine-solution/122791#122791) for details on how to reproduce.

Comment: (While I know why _I am_ not fond of this post: would down-voters please comment?)

Comment: @greybeard, thanks and vote up. :)

Maybe because I post some wrong format code. :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Variable Names

Apart from the odd (non [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) compliant) variable casing, you also have a `temp` variable.  Names like `temp` are frowned upon as they convey nothing about what that variable represents.

### Repeated Tests

You do seem to repeat the tests `c==',' or c=='}':` a couple of times (lines 26 and 42. I think this could be [refactored](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring) into using a test string, similar to your `NoOps` variable.

For example, on line 42, instead of:

> ```
>         if c in NoOps or c==',' or c=='}':
> ```

You *could* just do

```
        if c in NoOps or c in CloseOps:
```

Assuming you had a variable `CloseOps` defined in the preamble, like this:

```
 CloseOps = ",}"
```

The same thing would apply for the repeated use of this test condition on line 26.

### Repeated Logic

The following code (lines 45 - 49 inclusive):

> ```
>         if lastKey:
>                 result[lastKey]=lastValue
>                 lastValue=''
>                 lastKey=''
>         state=READY
> ```

Appears to be an (almost) verbatim repeat of the logic contained upon lines 29 - 33 (inclusive):

> ```
>             if lastKey:
>                 result[lastKey]=lastValue
>                 lastValue=''
>                 lastKey=''
>                 state=READY
> ```

[Functional Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_decomposition) would dictate that such repeated logic be [refactored](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring) into it's own function.

### Numbers aren't Strings!

There exists a flaw in your code (which was not present in [the answer code to your last question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/121328/parsing-json-in-one-go#122119)), where-by JSON-encoded numbers are turned into strings in your resulting `dict`.

If you (using your `parse` function implementation from this question) do:

```
 >>> type(parse('{"foo":"1"}')['foo'])
```

This yields:

```
 <type 'str'>
```

(Which is fine, since here `"1"` **should** be a string.  However:

```
 >>> type(parse('{"foo":1}')['foo'])
```

**Also** yields:

```
 <type 'str'>
```

Which indicates an **error**, as this should be `<type 'int'>` if the JSON were decoded properly.

Comment: Thanks Tersosauros, agree with all of your comments. I want to confirm in general you think using one state variable is fine, comparing using two state variables for the state machine?

Comment: **Yes**, as I [said in my previous comment on the question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/122534/parsing-json-in-one-go-using-state-machine-solution/122791#comment-228786): "*you should generally only ever need to track one state per FSM. So since all your logic is contained within one, you would need only one `state` variable.*"
The only BIG problem with this code is the broken integer handling - the other issues (variable names, *a* repeated test condition, and one 4-line repeated block of code) are fairly *minor*.  Although, as a *review* site, they are warranted for this.

Comment: Thanks Tersosauros, I accepted all of your comments, and to fix the integer type issue, I think I can fix by using `int(lastValue)` to convert the value directly? How do you think? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, casting the value to an integer is what you need.  There was code to do this in my answer to the last version (#2) of this question.  The cast will need to be inside a try/except block to ensure that non-integer values are caught and treated as some other type (float for example) - this was the behaviour of the code you based this new code from.